# MySQL query based on results of another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL which looks like this.

```
+---------+------------+--------------+
| user_id |    key     |     value    |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|    1    | full_name  |  John Smith  |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|    1    | is_active  |      1       |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|    1    | user_level |Administrator |
+---------+------------+--------------+
```

I need to get value of key **full_name** where **user_id** is **1**, but only if value of key **is_active** is 1. I can do it with 2 separate queries, but I would like to know if it is possible to do it in a single query.

Note: I cannot change the structure of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use `join`s:

```
select tn.value
from t tn join
     t ta
     on tn.user_id = ta.user_id and ta.key = 'active'
where tn.key = 'fullname';
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need below query  by using `exists`

```
select t.value from your_table t where 
exists ( select 1 from your_table t1
         where t1.user_id=t.user_id 
         and t1.key='is_active'
       ) and t.key='full_name'
```

[DEMO IN MYSQL 8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79a754cc597fcbdda39c61294a7fb0a1)

```
 value
john smith
```